# Apple Watch input values via scribble only

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I'm working on WatchKit App. In this app, there are some fields that the user should fill it,

I searched how to deal with input fields in iWatch, and I found the following code:

```
presentTextInputController(withSuggestions: ["1"], allowedInputMode:   WKTextInputMode.plain) { (arr: [Any]?) in

        if let answers = arr as? [String] {

            if let answer = answers[0] as? String {

                self.speechLabel.setText(answer)
            }
        }
    }
```

and this code gives me two choices: Diction and scribble, i.e

[image: scribble and Dictation]

In my App, I want to support only the scribble not both of them,

I tried to pass **withSuggestions** parameter as nil, but the app direct me to dictiation, not to scribble.

Is there a way to let the user only use scribble?

Comment: No, Dictation has to be there in every case. Especially so, because Scribble is only available for a small number of languages, while Dictation is available for a bigger number of languages.